# Using angular, Show drop-down list only when search button is clicked insted of clicking on drop-down

Tags: angularjs

In my requirement Initially it will show only search button not drop-down. Now, I need to show select list option directly when user click on search button instead of clicking on drop-down list. So I can get options when I click on search button and I can select any of them and once selected one option need to show another drop-down.  Here is my code
    `<a><button>search</button></a>
    <select><option value="">A</option><option value="">B</option>
    <option value="">C</option>
    <option value="">D</option>
</select>`

here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8bhvhq62/3/.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ng-disabled` directive here which would enable and disable the dropdown

**Markup**

```
<a><button ng-click="enabled=true">search</button></a>

<select ng-model="test" ng-disabled="!enabled">
    <option value="">A</option>
    <option value="">B</option>
    <option value="">C</option>
    <option value="">D</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="test1" ng-disabled="!enabled">
    <option value="">1</option>
    <option value="">2</option>
    <option value="">3</option>
    <option value="">4</option>
    <option value="">5</option>
</select>
```

[**Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8bhvhq62/3/)

Comment: Thanks Pankaj. But this will only disable the drop-down, while want to show drop-down list(not drop-down menu) only after search is clicked , and not only that want to show list of drop-down directly when clicked on search button.